# Are the variables stored in the Node.JS Express global namespace private to the current request?

Tags: node.js, express, security, global

Node.JS Express apps have a *global* object that acts as a "bag" you can attach data/objects to that is available to all the code in your application:

```
// Create an appRoot global variable that tells the code base what the root directory of this app is.
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);
```

My main concern is that I need to be sure that the *global* object is only global in the sense that all the code that operates in the context of **the current client request** an other has access the data in that object, and that the data is not available *between* or *across* requests.  Otherwise I could be leaking data that must remain private to a particular request or user.

To make sure I'm being crystal clear, let's take an example scenario:

- GET request #1: The name "john doe" is stored in *global.userName*
- GET request #2: At the start of the request, **global.UserName** is unassigned and absolutely does *not* contain "john doe"

In other words, is the *global* object reinitialized *with every single request* or does it persist as long as the server is operational, available to all requests that reach the server and there aren't any "tricks" that could lead to unwanted data leakage across server requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object is global to the entire node.js process. It doesn't have anything to do with Express. However, Express does have a few objects with different scopes that you can use for persisting data across a client request, or event across all client requests. From the Express docs:

[res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals)

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  res.locals.authenticated = ! req.user.anonymous;
  next();
});
```

[app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)

> The app.locals object has properties that are local variables within the application... Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application, in contrast with res.locals properties that are valid only for the lifetime of the request.

The Express `app.locals` object is similar to the node.js global object insofar as it being maintained in memory across multiple requests. However, it's local to an instance of Express, and should that instance be deleted, so will the app.locals object. The node.js `global` object differs in that it will stick around for the lifecycle of the entire node.js process.

Comment: So if I understand you, if I change all my code from "global." to "res.locals." I should have the request-only scope that I desire, while having the data available to all any code in my app that is executed during the current request?

Comment: Not entirely. The caveat is that you'll only have the `res.locals` object available to you when the `res` object is in scope (i.e. in your request/response handlers). You'll have to pass this object around otherwise. With the `global` object, you could just reference it's properties in any file anywhere within your application... But otherwise, yes, `res.locals` will give you the request only scope you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, global variables will persist for any request. Unless you spin another instance of your node application. If you're looking to some authentication/session tools there are quite a lot out there, like [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) or [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser)